# How to install UIkit 3 in Laravel using npm?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm, uikit

I'm currently trying to install and include [UIkit 3](https://getuikit.com) in my Laravel application using npm.

What I've done so far:

- I installed UIkit in the NodeJS console (worked)
- I included the SASS files (worked)

But now, I'm having problems with the JavaScript.
I followed these instructions: https://wpkb.org/add-uikit-3-to-your-laravel-app/ but Chrome doesn't seem to like it :(

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
    at app.js:32507
    at insertNodes (app.js:32523)
    at before (app.js:32507)
    at app.js:32513
    at insertNodes (app.js:32523)
    at after (app.js:32512)
    at UIkitComponent.write (app.js:38975)
    at app.js:34575
    at runTasks (app.js:33456)
    at Object.flush (app.js:33434)
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to install UIkit 3 in a Laravel 6 application is to use the package I've made, which will set install both UIkit and Vue.js and give you a nice UIkit template, including all the auth templates needed for a login/register system.

https://github.com/Torrix/laravel-ui-uikit

[image: Screenshot of UIkit running in Laravel]